# Denying IPs using IIS6

Tags: iis

I am granting certain IPs on IIS6 and deny the rest of IPs,

There are users who use the app from network, and I grant network IP range and it works.

Also local apps can access the application.

I grant a Real IP of a client machine, but I cannot connect the APP through the server Real IP.

What is chances.

Thanks

Comment: Does it work when you allow everybody through from the real IP's ? I think you have another firewall in the way.

Comment: yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do this kind of thing (regardless of application server, operating system, etc) on some level of firewall.  It makes the rulesets easier to analyse and update, rather than having server-specific denial rules.

I suggest you have a look at the Rules on Windows Firewall, and see if you can do what you want there.  It should make it considerably easier to trace the path of packets, and hopefully help you solve your own problem.